# How do I iterate over request.getParamterNames()?

Tags: grails

I'm using Grails 1.2.1.  Within a Grails method that references the HttpServletRequest object, how do I iterate over the request.getParameterNames() enumeration?  This doesn't work ...

```
    protected void doCacheTransport(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {               
            def url = request.getParameter("url")
            request.getParameterNames().each { 
                def paramName = it
                if (paramName != "url") { 
                    remoteUrl << "&" << paramName << "=" << request.getParameter(paramName)
                }   // if
            }   // each
```

I included the 'def url = request.getParameter("url")' line in my debugger to prove to myself that the parameter "url" indeed is defined.  However, the loop skips over everything.

Thanks for any additional info.  - Dave

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure why your code isn't working, since it looks OK (assuming that remoteUrl is declared outside of the each closure. In any case, this can be simplified quite a bit. First, by leveraging the [getParameterMap() method of ServletRequest](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/Se) and second, by using the obscure but very powerful [inject method](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#inject%28java.lang.Object,%20groovy.lang.Closure%29) from the Groovy collections API.

Inject takes an initial value (which I'm presuming you set remoteUrl to in your actual code), and then iterates over a collection, passing an accumulated value (or the initial value on the first pass through), and the item. This is very convenient for calculating a value whose result is somehow derived from every element in a collection.

That said, I think you can do something like this to get the result you want:

```
protected void doCacheTransport(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    def remoteUrl = request.parameterMap.entrySet().inject('http://someurl.example.com/?key=1828372') { url, entry ->
        if (entry.key == "url") return url
        else url << "&${entry.key}=${entry.value}"
    }
    // ...
```

}

If you can provide more details on what, exactly you are doing, I can provide a more helpful example.